# UICollectionView x3 Within each other creating a collection view slider within a header collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I was wondering if anyone can show/help me.
As you can see in image 2 that I am trying to create a card slider, within my UICOLLECTIONVIEW at the top.

I am aware that to create a UICollectionView slider you need to first create the collectionview to hold the slider then another within it. So all together I have 3 UICOLLECTIONVIEWS within each other.

I have been following tutorials to get this far but I can’t figure this one out. Image one is where I am currently.
But currently, all I seem to be doing is overlaying the current UICollection not making it go within it, as you can see in image 1.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[[image]

```
import UIKit

class MyFeedsHeader: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private let cellId = "appCellId"

    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {

        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return iv

    }()

    let feedsTitle: UILabel = {
        let title = UILabel()
        title.text = "Feeds"
        title.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
       return title
    }()


    let followingLabel: UILabel = {
        let title = UILabel()
        title.text = "00 Following"
        title.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        title.textColor = .lightGray
        return title
    }()


    // --------------------

    let appsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
//        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return collectionView
    }()


    //--------------------


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(profileImageView)
        profileImageView.anchor(top: self.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 16, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 50, height: 50)

        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5 / 1

        addSubview(feedsTitle)
        feedsTitle.anchor(top: self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        addSubview(followingLabel)
        followingLabel.anchor(top: feedsTitle.bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

       setupViews()

        self.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // ---------------------------------- remove below if can't figure out


    func setupViews() {
        // --------

        appsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        appsCollectionView.delegate = self

        appsCollectionView.register(AppCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        addSubview(appsCollectionView)


        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[v0]-8-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": appsCollectionView]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": appsCollectionView]))


        //--------
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    }
```

```
 class AppCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            setupViews()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        func setupViews() {
            backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with the outermost `UICollectionView` first, and as you get each one working you can move on to the next.

To get more detail on exactly what is going on with the app currently you can use the [View Debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html) to see if everything is nested correctly and any constraints are doing what they should.

To get the effect you are looking for your first stop should be implementing the methods coming from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`like `sizeForItemAt`, `insetForSectionAt`, & `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt`. These will define spacing and layout for the cells to interact with.

These delegate methods are all part of the protocol `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` which means that your collection view (who's delegate you set to `self` AKA `MyFeedsHeader`) will ask your class `MyFeedsHeader` for information about how to layout the cells if `MyFeedsHeader` has the functions on it. The is the same thing you did with the `func collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection`.

Hope that points you in the right direction! Best of luck!

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to swift so I don't fully understand what you mean. Is there anyway you could show me if possible, I have added another image to describe further what i'm trying to do, also I must add the code above is the file of the Blue HeaderCollectionView. So the AppCell class is me trying to add the green CollectionView. Hope I am explaining this correctly to you. Many thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: You're all good! Thanks for clarifying your question - I added some clarification to my original answer. I'm not sure exactly how the tutorial you are following is setting things up but hopefully that info helps. Let me know if you have any other specific questions.